# Proxy chain in python

Tags: python, proxy

I would like to set up a proxy chain in python.

With no proxy, it gives :

```
MACHINE ---> INTERNET
```

With one proxy, classical connexion :

```
MACHINE ---> Proxy ---> INTERNET
```

What I would like :

```
MACHINE ---> Proxy ---> Proxy ---> Proxy ---> INTERNET
```

Is there a way I can do this in python ? I don't want to use this solution :

```py
import requests

proxies = {
  'http': 'http://10.10.1.10:3128',
  'https': 'http://10.10.1.10:1080',
}

requests.get('http://example.org', proxies=proxies)
```

As I would like to connect to the proxies, not just send a request through them, because I want to use them after and keep connected to all of them. To connect to a proxy I do :

```py
import os
from elevate import elevate
elevate(show_console=False)
os.popen('netsh winhttp set proxy 175.106.10.226:51630')
```

This means : I request an UAC elevation, because the netsh winhttp set proxy command requires higher permissions, and when I got the elevation for my whole script I run every command I want. But is there a cmd command to set up a chain proxy ? Or a way to do it with python ?

Comment: You can't do it with `requests` but you still have opportunity to implement it on socket level. Check [this](https://github.com/pagekite/PySocksipyChain) out.

Comment: This seems pretty interesting, I'm checking it and will try to adapt my code to see if I can do what I want. Thanks !

Comment: https://github.com/pagekite/PySocksipyChain Hehehe... "This is a modified version of socksipy, which supports arbitrary chaining of proxy servers and various modes of TLS/SSL encryption." Pretty seems like it's what I want right ? Thanks a lot ! I'll post the answer when I will have it

Comment: I am not familiar with lib but it seems like you need to use `adddefaultproxy()` few times to chain proxies. You can try to replace `socket.socket` with `socksocket` from lib, but I have no idea will it affect `requests` library or not.

Comment: I read a few documentation, this seems to be a very old library, as it says "not supported yet : python 2"  there : https://github.com/spumer/PySocksChain.

Comment: And I can't even import it : py -m pip install https://github.com/spumer/PySocksChain.git
Collecting https://github.com/spumer/PySocksChain.git
  Downloading https://github.com/spumer/PySocksChain.git
     | 123 kB 1.1 MB/s
  ERROR: Cannot unpack file C:\Users\ELVE~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-unpack-z8fhlo0a\PySocksChain.git (downloaded from C:\Users\ELVE~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-req-build-qt7pcfzd, content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8); cannot detect archive format
ERROR: Cannot determine archive format of C:\Users\ELVE~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-req-build-qt7pcfzd

Comment: Actually there's not so much code, you can download it, put folder in your project and try to import. I'm sure that there's not so much changes in `socket` module, so it won't take too much time to let it work with your python version.

Comment: Yeah I'll try, that's a great idea doing the manual import.

Comment: Okay, I now have my answer : this is not what I'm looking for... This works the same way the request solution does, only allowing the script to perform requests through a proxy, not setting up a proxy for the whole computer... Yet I can make a chain proxy, aah ! ^^'

Comment: You wanted to set proxy on whole computer?

Comment: Yeah like, my python script sets up the whole proxy chain, and then I can use firefox or chrome or anything that needs internet and it will pass through the chain before

Comment: You can try to set a local proxy which will redirect rquests with chain

Comment: You mean if I set a local proxy I'll be able to redirect requests to a chain proxy ? But how to create that chain ? ^^' That's a point...

Comment: I mean to start proxy in python which will forward al requests through defined chain of proxies.

Comment: Yeah okay... I may try this